# Spring - two persistence units with different JPA providers

Tags: spring, hibernate, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa, persistence-unit

Is it possible to have two persistence units, one with Hibernate to work with some entities and another with EclipseLink to work with other entities in Spring framework?

Comment: Thank you for answer, do you have any example or configuration code snippet for this case?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<bean id="schema1EM" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  ...
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      ...
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.example.domain.schema1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schema2EM" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  ...
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
      ...
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.example.domain.schema2"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.example.data.schema1" entity-manager-factory-ref="schema1EM"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.example.data.schema2" entity-manager-factory-ref="schema2EM"/>
```

`schema1EM` will be assigned to all repositories declared under the package `org.example.data.schema1` and `schema2EM` will be assigned to those under `org.example.data.schema2`.  You will have to segregated the domain classes and repository interfaces by packages so that the Spring auto-wiring can work.